# auto refresh page

Tags: javascript

I need to refresh a web page on the time i get from the user. That's fine. But how i do make

that permanent. Say, the user selects 30secs, and makes it permanent, I need to refresh every

30 secs. I tried $_SESSION, ineffective. Pls don't suggest cookies.

Comment: You need to use cookies, or POST it to the session.

Comment: but what if cookies have been disabled?

Comment: Agreed that cookie must be used, or you must send the selected time back to the server to be stored in session and outputted on subsequent page loads.

Comment: @JAAulde: how to know whether the client has enabled them?

Comment: In the [javascript cookie library](http://code.google.com/p/cookies/) I wrote, I test by trying to set a cookie and then reading it back. If I don't get back my value, I know cookies are not enabled. I exposed this functionality with a test() method.

Comment: If you are asking about cookies being disabled, what about if JS is disabled? It kind of blows the whole thing out of the water.

Answer (score 0):

if cookies disabled, try using localstorage instead...

Comment: Srsly? If cookies are disabled then the odds of the user having a browser that implements localstorage or that user has enabled it are basically zero.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to persist the user's selection in some manner.

Cookies, session variable server-side, URL query parameter, localstorage - these are all options.

URL query parameters and SLaks's suggestion of POSTing let you keep different settings for different tabs opened simultaneously, if that matters to you.

EDIT: by URL query parameter I mean redirection, using `window.location`, to something like `http://example.com/foo?refresh=30` and later parsing `window.location.search`yourself or using [existing code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-querystring-values-with-jquery) for it.